# How to get headers when url is called? [ Angular5 ]

Tags: angular, header, angular2-routing, url-routing, angular5

I want to get request headers when URL is called.

When user clicked link button, this button trigger to run angular application in a new window. and this button send user email, password and token in headers of request. I want to get request headers but I don't know how to get when URL is accessed. I searched and find to how to get headers when call api in service but no article how to get headers through angular routes.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't access request headers for currently displayed page via javascript unless you do another http request with the same url manually.